# How to exclude action methods frm validation in struts2

Tags: struts2

How to exclude action methods from validation in struts2 ... for example i wann do validation for one action login with two fileds and other action method in same action class say test methode with filed message..... how can i do it?? using one xml file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following to your xml config file in order to change your validation interceptor.

```
<interceptor-ref name="validation">
      <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse,YOUR_METHOD_NAME</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

Alternatively you can annotate the method with

```
@org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.SkipValidation
```